# How to make a table's specific column unique to another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
Tag      | Song
_________|___________
tagName  | songTitle
song_id  |
```

I want to make `tagName` unique to `song_id` using MySQL.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you want to do, but if you want to ensure that a column's values are all unique, then you can add a unique constraint to that column.

Comment: i want to make tagName unique to song_id.

Answer (score 0):

In your database just add unique key to the the tagname column.So it will not allow duplicate entry.

Comment: Yes, it will make tagname unique. But, that is not what i want. tagName can have duplicate entries but uniquely associated with song_id. for example, song_id = 1 cannot be associated with same tagName. But, song_id= 1 and song_id=2 can be associated with same tagName.